# What is the formula to convert geodetic coordinates to state plane?

Tags: coordinates, datum, state-plane

I know there are tools that can do the conversion like pyproj, but I'm actually interested in the formula for computing it. Or if it's done with a big lookup table. I would love some information on how it's performed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you may find [Formula For State Plane to Lat/Lon Conversion](https://community.esri.com/thread/106211) at GeoNet useful. Posters here outlined resources for the math behind State Plane to Geographic Coordinates.

I'd pay particular attention to a manual from EPSG entitled ["Geomatics Guidance Note 7, part 2 Coordinate Conversions & Transformations including Formulas"](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-2.pdf?ver=2018-10-12-153840-577) and to ["John P. Snyder's Map Projections: A Working Manual"](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf) (PDF).

There is some good discussion in that first link culminating in two SQL queries for running through the individual conversions for lat/lon, I'd recommend checking those out, as well.